# Kotlin equivalent of %@ in swift

Tags: swift, string, kotlin, string-formatting

i am new to kotlin.
In swift i can do :

```
let endpoint = "categories/" + "%@/issues/"
let number = "4"
let finalstring = String(format: endpoint, number)
```

The final output of the string will be : categories/4/issues/ as a string .

I have looked at string format in kotlin but it's only work afterwards meaning that i can't define a template for my string and fill it later.

```
var value1 = "categories/"
var value2 = 4
var value3 = "/issues/"
println(java.lang.String.format("%s%d%s", value1, value2, value3))
```

This give me the same result but it's mean that i have to manualy write the end of the string.

What i want to do i to have a template for my string in a Road file.
Then complet my string at the run time. The probleme is that the part of my string that i want to complete is in the middle of the string.
Of course i can use substring and remplace but i am looking for a clean way to do it as in swift.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: No Kotlin expert, but it could be cleaner in Swift too: `"categories/\(number)/issues/"`

Comment: Actually `%@` is Objective C, not Swift. A format string is a Cocoa Foundation feature, not a Swift language feature.

Comment: Also, string interpolation is way safer than format string.

Comment: if i try to use \(number) i got illegal escape '\('
Also i could do $number if wanted to do something like this.
But i want my string to be on a different file and leave a kind of blank that i can fill at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your format string up front with all the constant parts, and with relevant placeholders (like `%d` for numbers) (more info in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)).

Later, use the regular Java `String.format()` later with the parameters:

```
// define this constant up front
val format = "categories/%d/issues/"

// and then later:
val categoryId = 4
println(String.format(format, categoryId))
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible option would be to define a local function that does the formatting:

```
fun requestString(number: Int) = "categories/$number/issues/"

val finalString = requestString(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer right there in your example, you just have to put it together.
String.format takes `%s` as placeholder for a String or `%d` for a number (and [many more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) placeholder options).

So your template string would be: `"categories/%d/issues/"`. To format it you use:

```
val format = "categories/%d/issues/"
val number = 4
val string = String.format(format, number)
```

---

About interpolation vs formatting, they can be used in different situations.
If you have the template string available in source code then you would use interpolation:

```
val string = "categories/${category.id}/issues/"
```

But when you have no control over the string, because it comes from an external source (such as a file), then you would have to use the formatting.